# Create new command for a specific font style

Tags: fonts, renewcommand

How can I make a new command of

```
{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont <text here>}
```

I have worked before with `\renewcommand` for mathematical formulas but I'm not sure how to do it with text formatting.

Comment: `\newcommand{\foo}[1]{{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont #1}}`?

Comment: Ah yes! I thought one needed something else.

Comment: If the argument will never contain several paragraphs (i.e. `\par` tokens), use `\newcommand*` to ease tracking of forgotten closing braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best method is

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcourier}{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont}
```

Use the command name you prefer, but beware that its meaning would be overridden if already defined, so you might want

```
\newcommand{\textcourier}{}
```

just before.